# How to scale SVG to fit the div

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to use the same SVG on different DIV's. However, I would like the SVG to uniformly scale to it the div.

CodeSandbox link to the working example of what I have is below

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-wing-9f985w?file=/src/Icon.js

What I have

[image]

What I would like

[image]

How do I achieve this? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove the width and height attributes of the svg elements, calculate the height of each conteiner and set the width of the svg iqual to the height of the conteiner. This works since the icon is square (see viewBox="0 0 500 500")

```js
//all containers
let cc = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
cc.forEach((c) => {
  //get the height of each container
  let height = c.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  //get the svg element inside each conteiner
  let svg = c.querySelector("svg");
  //set the width of the svg element
  svg.style.width = height;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0.15rem;
  padding: 0.15rem;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.15rem;
  padding: 0.15rem;
}

.Text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.15rem;
  padding: 0.15rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="container">
    <div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="Icon" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <path fill="none" id="mg" stroke="#000" stroke-width="36" stroke-linecap="round" d="m280,278a153,153 0 1,0-2,2l170,170m-91-117 110,110-26,26-110-110"></path>
      </svg></div>
    <h2 class="Text">Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="Icon" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <use href="#mg"/>
      </svg></div>
    <h2 class="Text">Start editing to see some magic happen! if the magic does not happen, keep editing</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="Icon"  viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <use href="#mg"/>
      </svg></div>
    <h2 class="Text">Start editing to see some magic happen! if the magic does not happen, keep editing. Even after typing nothing happens, you need to just give u ;-)</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Observation**: since you are using the same icon, instead of repeating the code for the magnifying glass you can give the path an id (id="mg") and reuse it with `<use>`

Comment: Great answer! There's a lot to learn

Comment: (typo ) It is necessary to replace in the text Observation ... `pth` with `mg`

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for the guidance. Up-voted & accepted. I want to do this in React web app, so, I think I may have to do it a bit differently. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can save the SVG inside an .svg file and use img element to reference that tag (e.g. src="icon.svg"), this will give more flexibility in scaling the SVG

For more details see: [How to Scale SVG](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)

Note: I think it will look better if you align the icon top instead of scaling the icon